# Why can't I delete a model instance with related objects?

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I'm trying to delete a `User` object in a Django app, but I keep getting an `IntegrityError` in a related object when deleting the `User`. The related object looks like this:

```
class Unfollowing(models.Model):
    source = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='unfollowings_by')
    target = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='unfollowings_of')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

But when deleting a `User`, I get an error like the following:

> IntegrityError: update or delete on table "auth_user" violates foreign key constraint "source_id_refs_id_5b69e09fc6161c2a" on table "core_unfollowing"
>   DETAIL:  Key (id)=(6439) is still referenced from table "core_unfollowing".

What's the deal? Shouldn't the related `Unfollowing` objects be deleted automatically when an associated `User` is deleted? For what it's worth, I added an explicit `on_delete=models.CASCADE` to both `Unfollowing.source` and `Unfollowing.target` (even though that's the default) and I still got the same error.

Comment: You aren't using a proxy model by chance (and an older Django)? https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16128

Comment: @karthikr: `on_delete` is a parameter for model fields: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony: Nope, not a proxy model.

Comment: Alternatively (and speculatively) might it have to do with having two FKs to the `User` model, and the `on_delete` not being able to follow both `related_name`s?

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony: I thought so, too, but explicitly deleting the related models via `user.unfollowings_by.all().delete(); user.unfollowings_of.all().delete(); user.delete()` resulted in a similar error.

Answer (score 2):

That's weird indeed. Here's a couple of things I would try:

First, did you update the database schema after adding `on_delete=models.CASCADE`?. If not, it wouldn't do any effect. You can double check if `ON DELETE CASCADE` is activated by dumping the database schema directly, not figuring it out from Django.

Seems to me this is more a db engine related error than Django's. If you're 100% positive `ON DELETE CASCADE` is activated in auth_user table and the related tables, then you can try to delete a user directly from your sql client. If it works, and the same user give you trouble from Django (or a similar user, given the fact that you erased the first one), then try to dump the SQL query Django is doing and repeat it from your sql client.

This is the approach I would take. Also, check if this happens with a specific user or every user, check for hanging references in the Unfollowing tables. Maybe also there exist an old table you used to have and that's the one giving you problem.

I'll focus the research directly with the database and a sql client and after I managed to get it working there, move back to Django.

This is more the path I'll follow than an answer since this seems to be a very specific problem.

I hope this might help a little.

Good luck!