# Mix raw and ORM operations within the same Django transaction?

Tags: django

Is it possible?

I have a simple delete statement via ORM (because [there are cascade delete Integrity Error problems when using raw sql delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246090/why-cant-i-delete-a-model-instance-with-related-objects)) and a complex update query via connection.execute(). And i'd like to put them both inside a transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.

```
from django.db import transaction

def viewfunc(request):
    # This code executes in autocommit mode (Django's default).
    do_stuff()

    with transaction.atomic():
        # This code executes inside a transaction.
        do_more_stuff()
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic